# Linked server from SQL Server (RDS) to Oracle (RDS) in AWS

Tags: sql-server, oracle, amazon-rds

Is it possible to have linked server established between SQL Server (RDS) to Oracle (RDS) in AWS?

I tried to get help of Oracle Support and I understand that if we use Oracle Database Gateway this is possible.

I am interested to hear if any such feature exist from SQL Server also .

Comment: I once linked a postgres database server to SQL Server via SSMS - both were hosted in RDS. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: The issue with using Oracle Database Gateway is , its licensed and not free